# Mocking functional component in jest throws "Invalid variable access" error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I tried mocking a functional component (that uses Hooks) the following way:

`jest.mock('./common/MyComp', () => () => <div>MockedMyComp</div>);`

But its throwing this error:

```
 file.js: babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: React
    Whitelisted objects: Array, ArrayBuffer, Boolean, DataView, Date, Error, EvalError, Float32Array, Float64Array, Function, Generator, GeneratorFunction, Infinity, Int16Array, Int32Array, Int8Array, InternalError, Intl, JSON, Map, Math, NaN, Number, Object, Promise, Proxy, RangeError, ReferenceError, Reflect, RegExp, Set, String, Symbol, SyntaxError, TypeError, URIError, Uint16Array, Uint32Array, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray, WeakMap, WeakSet, arguments, expect, jest, require, undefined, console, DTRACE_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION, DTRACE_NET_STREAM_END, DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST, DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE, DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST, DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE, COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION, COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION_CLOSE, COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST, COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE, COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST, COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE, global, process, Buffer, clearImmediate, clearInterval, clearTimeout, setImmediate, setInterval, setTimeout, __core-js_shared__.
    Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.
```

I've seen a lot of examples mock components this way so I expected it to work in my case too.

Answer (score 2):

so don't use JSX in mock declaration. Init it with `jest.fn()` and later provide mocked value.

```
...
import MyComp from './common/MyComp';
...

jest.mock('./common/MyComp', () => jest.fn());
// jest.mock('./common/MyComp'); will work as well

it ('...', () => {
 MyComp.mockReturnValue(<div>MockedMyComp</div>);
```

If you use Enzyme consider using [`shallow()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/shallow.html) instead of `mount()` then you would not need mocking subcomponents like above.

Comment: Doing `mockReturnValue` throws `Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type...` error. Also what's the difference between returning a div in my div and `jest.mock('./common/MyComp');` ?

Comment: With Typescript, I can call `.mockReturnValue` if I do this `(MyComp as jest.Mock)`, but it should work straightforward in vanilla JS

Comment: @JunlongWang right. That's because TS checks for original code/types and have no idea how `jest.mock()` replaces whole module. As alternative to putting `as jest.Mock` everywhere you can also declare `const importedSome = some as jest.Mock` once, outside the `describe`. And refer this const instead of what have been imported.